# How can I integrate the Dynatrace APM platform with the Play framework?

Tags: playframework, dynatrace

Currently I have installed the DynaTrace agent, server and collector. I'm starting my Play application like this:

```
path/to/play_app/bin > ./my_play_application_name -Dagentpath:/home/sagara/software/dynatrace-6.2/agent/lib64/libdtagent.so=name=PlayServer_Monitoring,server=ubuntu:9998
```

I also tried adding the same to the JAVA_OPTS:

```
JAVA_OPTS=-agentpath:/home/sagara/software/dynatrace-6.2/agent/lib64/libdtagent.so=name=PlayServer_Monitoring,server=ubuntu:9998
```

In both cases, the Dynatrace server did not recognize any agents.

Am I doing something wrong? 
I'm running Ubuntu Linux with Oracle Java 8.

Dynatrace server is running locally at port 9998 and the agent library exists in the "agentpath".

Also, no logs exist the Dynatrace Agent log directory.

Answer (score 1):

make sure your play server can connect to ubuntu on port 9998 - assuming that this is the machine where the dynatrace server is installed. make sure there is no firewall. also make sure that the collector runs on that machine

Any console output in your play app that would show any dynatrace agent output?

Comment: Also - take advantage of our online community portal and our discussion forums for dynatrace releated questions: http://community.dynatrace.com